# No Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, and now no Ethernet on Ubuntu Jammy

Tags: drivers, usb, bluetooth, internet, ethernet

I’m new to Ubuntu and installed it for about a week ago on my Acer Aspire ES1-521 laptop.
From the moment I installed it, the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth haven’t worked at all; however the usb Ethernet mobile hotspot I used from my iPhone worked great. Today I woke up and now the Ethernet will not work with no explanation as to why.
It will read me plugging in the iPhone and open its photos and apps but will not read it as a hotspot. So my laptop is completely incapable of internet access.
Since I am a pretty new user to this, my question is if there’s any easy fix to solve these problems?
Anything I’ve seen on the internet is in wording that’s impossible for a new person to decipher, so please help me with this.

**The touchpad built in to my laptop has also been unusable since I’ve installed Ubuntu, but that’s something I can fix myself with a usb mouse.

Comment: Does the phone tether work if you reboot into an older kernel?  If it does, edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb`